# Why I get com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I would like to send datas to server, but it get this exception: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `retrofit2.Call` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
, despite, the server gives me HttP 200

I read a lot, but I cant solve this problem

UPDATE: This error is appear when I use Call<> in my interface

```
Object class:
data class CrmLeadActivityApiModel(
    @JsonProperty("oid")var oid: String = "",
    @JsonProperty("Subject") var subject: String? = null,
    @JsonProperty("StartOn") var startOn: Date = Date(),
    @JsonProperty("EndOn") var endOn: Date = Date(),
    @JsonProperty("Recurrence") var recurrence: Boolean = false,
    @JsonProperty("CrmOpportunityOid") var crmOpportunityOid: String = "",
    @JsonProperty("Location") var location: String? = null,
    @JsonProperty("Description") var description: String? = null,
    @JsonProperty("SendNotificationToParticipant") var sendNotificationToParticipants: Boolean = false,
    @JsonProperty("SyncStatus") var syncStatus: Int? = null,
)  {}

api:
    @POST("crm/saveActivities")
    suspend fun sendCrmLeadActivities(@Body crmLeadActivities: List<CrmLeadActivityApiModel>) : Call<List<ResponseBody>>

Retrofit:


        var builder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        builder = BuildTypeInitializations.setupInterceptor(builder)

        val objectMapper = ObjectMapper().registerModule(KotlinModule())
        objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true)
        val factory = JacksonConverterFactory.create(objectMapper)

        builder
            .addInterceptor(CustomResponseInterceptor(authApi,prefManager))
            .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(factory)
            .client(builder.build())
            .build()
            .create(CrmApi::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake, because I used suspend keyword az Call<> at the same time, after that I remooved suspend keyword, the error is gone.